# Why does Isabella have a bow on her Fireside Girls hat instead of a diamond?

Tags: character, phineas-and-ferb

I've just noticed in *Phineas and Ferb* that while all of the other Fireside Girls have hats with a diamond, Isabella Garcia-Shapiro has a bow on hers instead.

This is seen clearly in the episode "Isabella and the Temple of Sap":

[image]

Is there any reason for this, or just to make Isabella look more like her standard look?

Comment: [Most of their uniforms are inconsistent with each other](http://phineasandferb.wikia.com/wiki/Fireside_Girls#Outfits)... From that link: "an orange beret with red diamond (except Isabella, who has a red bow instead of a diamond, Candace, who **wears a brown beret**, and Melissa, who **doesn't wear a beret at all**)"

Answer (score 3):

My assumption would be either

a) Because she's in charge and can add personal flair to her outfit.

or

b) Because she's in charge and it's to identify her as in charge.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.